# Making on Offline form using JotForm

Tags: html, forms, offline, jotform

i'm a beginner and just learning about HTML.  I just need a point in the right direction here. Any tutorials you can point me to would be greatly appreciated.

I am trying to create an offline version of this form I created on JotForm-http://form.jotform.us/form/40855701907154

I would like it to save the data a user inputs into an excel file.

I have tried saving the page offline by clicking 'save page as' but the 'submit' button doesn't appear.

I've been trying to understand this tutorial-http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html.
Do I open the HTML file in notepad and try to edit it? If so, how do i edit it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to save the data to the Excel file.. you must store it first in database, then display your database in php with this header:

```
<?php
// excel raw data
header("Content-type: application/vnd-ms-excel");

// define the name "results.xls"
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=results.xls");

// echo your database
include 'database.php';
?>
```

that is the simplest way for begginer... let me know if this work for you...